# Issue importing PyYAML, cltk

Tags: macos, pip, setuptools, pyenv, pyyaml

I just got a MacBook, cloned the project I was working on, and went to set up the python environment.  After creating the environment, I updated pip and tried installing the necessary libraries using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  The 3 libraries that are giving me issues are `cltk`, `PyYAML`, and `stanza`.

This is what it gives me after executing `pip install -r requirements.txt`:

```
Collecting PyYAML==5.4.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 56))
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [62 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      writing lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/top_level.txt
      /private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
      !!
      
              ********************************************************************************
              The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
      
              By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
              or your builds will no longer be supported.
      
              See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
              ********************************************************************************
      
      !!
        parsed = self.parsers.get(option_name, lambda x: x)(value)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/mikerabayda/repos/github.com/public/FastBridge/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/Users/mikerabayda/repos/github.com/public/FastBridge/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/Users/mikerabayda/repos/github.com/public/FastBridge/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 314, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 322, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 551, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 589, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 104, in add_defaults
          super().add_defaults()
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
        File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
        File "/private/var/folders/lk/14gmp9zs33512s20nwz_329c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-pbxz96he/overlay/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

In `requirements.txt` I noticed that it specifies versions of all the packages, I tried taking those out to let pip solve the dependency issues and get the same error.  I've tried deleting `cltk`, `PyYAML`, and `stanza` and pip installing them manually after downloading the others from `requirements.txt` but get similar dependency issues.

This is still all working on WSL on my other computer with a virtual environment using python `3.8.10`, but I can't get it to work on this new one.  I'm using `3.8.17` and have tried more recent python versions with 0 success.

Comment: this is my first question ever so apologies for the formatting

Comment: You might try this workaround: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/601#issuecomment-1639011671, but note, per the link in that comment AWS is advising against this b/c of an old CVE.  Sounds like proper upstream fix is in the works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-compose no longer building image (AttributeError: cython\_sources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708329/docker-compose-no-longer-building-image-attributeerror-cython-sources)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490435/attributeerror-cython-sources/77491847#77491847

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snyk shows a [critical security issue](https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-PYTHON-PYYAML-590151) with PyYAML==5.3.1. Fix by upgrading to version 6.0.1 instead.

Comment: Had to move from 6.0 to 6.0.1 to work on Mac

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in PyYAML `5.4.1` which is the version you are trying to install. It was opened last week and the workaround suggested is to use the previous minor version `5.3.1`.

More information here:
https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/724

So, in your `requirements.txt`:

```
...
PyYAML==5.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and i can't use another pyyaml version, so i've been thinking in to make download to the code and remove or comment the build system section in the pyproject.toml and installing the package for localhost using pip install in the location font code.