# setuptools DeprecationError when trying to build docker-compose python app

Tags: python, docker-compose, package

I'm trying to install **fastapi-pagination** library. When I add it to the requirements.txt and try to build docker compose, the error occurs:

```
    × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
#0 34.42   │ exit code: 1
#0 34.42   ╰─> [62 lines of output]
#0 34.42       /tmp/pip-build-env-leq01370/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/config/setupcfg.py:293: _DeprecatedConfig: Deprecated config in `setup.cfg`
#0 34.42       !!
#0 34.42       
#0 34.42               ********************************************************************************
#0 34.42               The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
#0 34.42       
#0 34.42               By 2023-Oct-30, you need to update your project and remove deprecated calls
#0 34.42               or your builds will no longer be supported.
#0 34.42       
#0 34.42               See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html for details.
#0 34.42               ********************************************************************************
```

The end of Traceback:

```
#0 34.17           raise AttributeError(attr)
#0 34.17       AttributeError: cython_sources
#0 34.17       [end of output]
#0 34.17   
#0 34.17   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 34.18 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 34.18 
#0 34.18 × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
#0 34.18 │ exit code: 1
#0 34.18 ╰─> See above for output.
#0 34.18 
#0 34.18 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 34.48 
#0 34.48 [notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.1 -> 23.2
#0 34.48 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Without fastapi-pagination everything works fine.

Comment: What is your base image? What is the full trace? This might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708329/docker-compose-no-longer-building-image-attributeerror-cython-sources/76710304#76710304

Comment: @β-εηοιτ-βε, thank you, your link was helpful

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem.

I was able to fix it by downgrading PyYaml to 5.3.1

In my requrements.txt it's looks like that

```
PyYAML==5.3.1
docker==6.0.1
docker-compose==1.29.2
```

Comment: The main point that docker-compose V1 EOL and nobody support it any more, unfortunately