# Build failed with aws ebcli on Python 3.11.4

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I try to install ebcli using `Python 3.11.4` (inside a venv, as per the [official instructions](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup#2-quick-start)) I get an error and I just can't get around it.

But If I try to install ebcli using `Python 3.8.10`(again inside a venv) it works.

The error looks like this:

```
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-yn_umd7x/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-yn_umd7x/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

- I already followed the [troubleshooting recommendations](https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup#4-troubleshooting), which consists on installing dependencies, and it didn't have any effect.
- I already googled for this specific issue and I can't find a solution. I did find [this issue](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/601) containing `AttributeError: cython_sources` which might be related, but I don't know what action to take from there.

Comment: It seem pyyaml issue did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708329/docker-compose-no-longer-building-image-attributeerror-cython-sources

Comment: Thanks @Ahtisham, you pointed me in the right direction. I had to run this command `pip install --force-reinstall -v "PyYAML==6.0.1" --no-build-isolation` for solving the error. If you want you can post an answer below (please include the specific command) and I will select it as the correct one. Otherwise I will do it.

Comment: You can upvote if you think community can benefit from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-compose no longer building image (AttributeError: cython\_sources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708329/docker-compose-no-longer-building-image-attributeerror-cython-sources)

Comment: Hi Anthony, yes it does help thank you. I follow your Youtube, and on top of all I learn from you there, you also answer my StackOverflow questions. You're amazing mate, thanks for everything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490435/attributeerror-cython-sources/77491847#77491847

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the pyyaml issue I had the similar issue when upgrading a legacy project from django 2 to 4:

You can have a look at this post: [Docker-compose no longer building image (AttributeError: cython_sources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708329/docker-compose-no-longer-building-image-attributeerror-cython-sources)

You can also try this

```
pip install "cython<3.0.0" && pip install --no-build-isolation pyyaml==6.0
```

Just as mentioned here: https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/724#issuecomment-1638636728

Or just as you did it:

```
pip install --force-reinstall -v "PyYAML==6.0.1" --no-build-isolation
```

Note: dowgrading to previous version should always be avoided as it may have serious security issue and that is why new version are released like in case of pyyaml.