# AttributeError: cython_sources

Tags: python, python-3.x, catboost, python-3.12

I am using:

```
python: 3.12

OS: Windows 11 Home
```

I tried to install `catboost==1.2.2`

I am getting this error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>py -3 -m pip install catboost==1.2.2
Collecting catboost==1.2.2
  Downloading catboost-1.2.2.tar.gz (60.1 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 60.1/60.1 MB 5.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [135 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=64.0
        Using cached setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (807 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.41.3-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
      Collecting jupyterlab
        Downloading jupyterlab-4.0.8-py3-none-any.whl (9.2 MB)
           ---------------------------------------- 9.2/9.2 MB 7.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting conan<=1.59,>=1.57
        Downloading conan-1.59.0.tar.gz (780 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 781.0/781.0 kB 4.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting async-lru>=1.0.0 (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading async_lru-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (6.1 kB)
      Collecting ipykernel (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading ipykernel-6.26.0-py3-none-any.whl (114 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 114.3/114.3 kB 6.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting jinja2>=3.0.3 (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading Jinja2-3.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 133.1/133.1 kB 7.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting jupyter-core (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading jupyter_core-5.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
      Collecting jupyter-lsp>=2.0.0 (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading jupyter_lsp-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
           ---------------------------------------- 66.0/66.0 kB 3.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0 (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading jupyter_server-2.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (378 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 378.6/378.6 kB 4.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting jupyterlab-server<3,>=2.19.0 (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading jupyterlab_server-2.25.1-py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
           ---------------------------------------- 59.0/59.0 kB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting notebook-shim>=0.2 (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading notebook_shim-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
      Collecting packaging (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
           ---------------------------------------- 53.0/53.0 kB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting tornado>=6.2.0 (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading tornado-6.3.3-cp38-abi3-win_amd64.whl (429 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 429.2/429.2 kB 9.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting traitlets (from jupyterlab)
        Downloading traitlets-5.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
           ---------------------------------------- 85.0/85.0 kB 4.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting requests<3.0.0,>=2.25 (from conan<=1.59,>=1.57)
        Downloading requests-2.31.0-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
           ---------------------------------------- 62.6/62.6 kB ? eta 0:00:00
      Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.26.6 (from conan<=1.59,>=1.57)
        Downloading urllib3-1.26.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl (143 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 143.8/143.8 kB 4.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
      Collecting colorama<0.5.0,>=0.3.3 (from conan<=1.59,>=1.57)
        Downloading colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
      Collecting PyYAML<=6.0,>=3.11 (from conan<=1.59,>=1.57)
        Downloading PyYAML-6.0.tar.gz (124 kB)
           -------------------------------------- 125.0/125.0 kB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [54 lines of output]
        running egg_info
        writing lib\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
        writing dependency_links to lib\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
        writing top-level names to lib\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
            main()
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
            json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
            return hook(config_settings)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
            return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
            self.run_setup()
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
            exec(code, locals())
          File "<string>", line 288, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
            return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
            return run_commands(dist)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
            dist.run_commands()
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 989, in run_command
            super().run_command(command)
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 318, in run
            self.find_sources()
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 326, in find_sources
            mm.run()
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 548, in run
            self.add_defaults()
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 586, in add_defaults
            sdist.add_defaults(self)
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 113, in add_defaults
            super().add_defaults()
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
            self._add_defaults_ext()
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
            self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
          File "<string>", line 204, in get_source_files
          File "C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-w9d6umo6\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
            raise AttributeError(attr)
        AttributeError: cython_sources
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1

      See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

      [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.1.2 -> 23.3.1
      [notice] To update, run: C:\Users\talta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Any workaround or solutions?

Comments and answers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Edit: Adding the work arounds which worked for people.**

**Two workarounds exist**:

1.Preinstall `cython<3`, then install `pyyaml` without build isolation, then install the rest of your dependencies "AttributeError: cython_sources" with Cython 3.0.0a10 #601 (comment)

```
$ pip install "cython<3.0.0" wheel
$ pip install "pyyaml==5.4.1" --no-build-isolation
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

2.Use a constraints file to force pip to use cython<3 at build time "AttributeError: cython_sources" with Cython 3.0.0a10 #601 (comment)

```
$ echo "cython<3" > /tmp/constraint.txt
$ PIP_CONSTRAINT=/tmp/constraint.txt pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Credit to @astrojuanlu

https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/601#issuecomment-1813963845

---

---

Looks like there is an ongoing issue for installation of `catboost==1.2.2`

git links:

https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/2520

https://github.com/catboost/catboost/issues/2469

`PyYAML` and `Cython` are the culprit.

Here is the main git : https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/601

Comment: Cython rather than Cypthon?