# No matching distribution found for pyyaml==6.0

Tags: python-3.x, linux

Any ideas how to solve that error? Looking at the trace I can't really see what's wrong. I haven't found any related solutions using google.

`$ pip install pyyaml==6.0`

```
  Collecting pyyaml==6.0
    Downloading PyYAML-6.0.tar.gz (124 kB)
      |████████████████████████████████| 124 kB 1.4 MB/s 
    Installing build dependencies ... done
    Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpimfk8et5_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmptwgswocr
        cwd: /tmp/pip-install-jtbm2j5w/pyyaml_43d97cbb4d494a94a99612f362c5e1f8
    Complete output (48 lines):
    running egg_info
    writing lib/PyYAML.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to lib/PyYAML.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to lib/PyYAML.egg-info/top_level.txt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/tmpimfk8et5_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/tmpimfk8et5_in_process.py", line 263, in main
        json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "/tmp/tmpimfk8et5_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        return hook(config_settings)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
        self.run_setup()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
        exec(code, locals())
      File "<string>", line 288, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
        return run_commands(dist)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 989, in run_command
        super().run_command(command)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 318, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 326, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 548, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 586, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 113, in add_defaults
        super().add_defaults()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_ext()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
        self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
      File "<string>", line 204, in get_source_files
      File "/tmp/pip-build-env-f2hncflc/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
        raise AttributeError(attr)
    AttributeError: cython_sources
    ----------------------------------------
  WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/2b/61d51a2c4f25ef062ae3f74576b01638bebad5e045f747ff12643df63844/PyYAML-6.0.tar.gz#sha256=68fb519c14306fec9720a2a5b45bc9f0c8d1b9c72adf45c37baedfcd949c35a2 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyyaml/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpimfk8et5_in_process.py get_requires_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmptwgswocr Check the logs for full command output.
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyyaml==6.0
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyyaml==6.0
```

My environment:

Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
5.15.92-1
Python 3.92

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details: I don't know what else I could write here.

Comment: how have you not found results on google?  the AttributeError line has hundreds of exact duplicate posts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker-compose no longer building image (AttributeError: cython\_sources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76708329/docker-compose-no-longer-building-image-attributeerror-cython-sources)

Comment: @anthonysottile Where in my question do you see anything about Docker?

Comment: the docker part isn't important -- that question's title is overly specific but their problem and solution is identical to yours

Answer (score 0):

You could just install pyyaml without the rest of it. This usually works for me when using prewritten scripts that are for older Python 3 versions.