# Cannot install tflite-model-maker using pip in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, anaconda, tflite

I am running the following command in my Jupyter Notebook in Windows,

```
!python -m pip config set global.cert D:\DDownloads\Cert.pem
!pip --cert "D:\DDownloads\Cert.pem" install tflite-model-maker
```

In response I am getting error:

```
Collecting tflite-model-maker
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (577 kB)
Collecting tf-models-official==2.3.0 (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached tf_models_official-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (840 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17.3 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tflite-model-maker) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=7.0.0 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tflite-model-maker) (10.0.1)
Collecting sentencepiece>=0.1.91 (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached sentencepiece-0.1.99-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (977 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tflite-model-maker) (4.9.3)
Collecting fire>=0.3.1 (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached fire-0.5.0.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: flatbuffers>=2.0 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tflite-model-maker) (23.5.26)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.10.0 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tflite-model-maker) (1.4.0)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of tflite-model-maker to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting tflite-model-maker
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (642 kB)
Collecting flatbuffers==1.12 (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached flatbuffers-1.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting tflite-model-maker
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (642 kB)
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (616 kB)
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (616 kB)
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (591 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-hub<0.10>=0.8.0 (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached tensorflow_hub-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Collecting tflite-model-maker
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (590 kB)
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (567 kB)
Collecting absl-py<0.11>=0.10.0 (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached absl_py-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
INFO: pip is still looking at multiple versions of tflite-model-maker to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting tflite-model-maker
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (499 kB)
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (190 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-hub>=0.8.0 (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached tensorflow_hub-0.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.3 kB)
Collecting tflite-model-maker
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (114 kB)
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (102 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (102 kB)
Collecting tf-models-official (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached tf_models_official-2.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Collecting tflite-model-maker
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
Collecting tf-nightly (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached tf_nightly-2.16.0.dev20231123-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
Collecting tf-models-nightly (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.15.0.dev20231123-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Collecting tflite-model-maker
  Using cached tflite_model_maker-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
Collecting tflite-support==0.1.0a0 (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached tflite-support-0.1.0a0.tar.gz (258 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11>=2.4 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tflite-support==0.1.0a0->tflite-model-maker) (2.11.1)
Requirement already satisfied: array-record in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (8.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: dm-tree in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (0.1.8)
Requirement already satisfied: etils>=0.9.0 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from etils[enp,epath,etree]>=0.9.0->tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: promise in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.20 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (3.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (5.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.19.0 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-metadata in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: termcolor in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (2.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toml in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (0.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (4.65.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow-datasets>=2.1.0->tflite-model-maker) (1.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from fire>=0.3.1->tflite-model-maker) (1.16.0)
Collecting Cython (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached Cython-3.0.5-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Collecting gin-config (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached gin_config-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting google-api-python-client>=1.6.7 (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached google_api_python_client-2.108.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
Collecting immutabledict (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached immutabledict-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
Collecting kaggle>=1.3.9 (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached kaggle-1.5.16.tar.gz (83 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker) (3.7.2)
Collecting oauth2client (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached oauth2client-4.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting opencv-python-headless (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached opencv_python_headless-4.8.1.78-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.22.0 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: py-cpuinfo>=3.3.0 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker) (8.0.0)
Collecting pycocotools (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached pycocotools-2.0.7-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl.metadata (1.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=6.0.0 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker) (6.0)
Collecting sacrebleu (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached sacrebleu-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (57 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in d:\ai\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker) (1.11.3)
Collecting seqeval (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached seqeval-1.2.2.tar.gz (43 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting tensorflow-model-optimization>=0.4.1 (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached tensorflow_model_optimization-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (914 bytes)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of tf-models-nightly to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting tf-models-nightly (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.15.0.dev20231122-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.15.0.dev20231121-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.15.0.dev20231120-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.15.0.dev20231119-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.15.0.dev20231118-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.15.0.dev20231117-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.15.0.dev20231116-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
INFO: pip is still looking at multiple versions of tf-models-nightly to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231115-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231114-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231113-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231112-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231111-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
INFO: This is taking longer than usual. You might need to provide the dependency resolver with stricter constraints to reduce runtime. See https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/backtracking for guidance. If you want to abort this run, press Ctrl + C.
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231110-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231109-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231108-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231107-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231106-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231105-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231104-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231103-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231102-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231101-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231031-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231030-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231029-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231028-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231027-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231026-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231025-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231024-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231022-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231021-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231020-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231019-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231018-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231017-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231016-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231015-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231014-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231013-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231012-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231011-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231010-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231009-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231008-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231007-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231006-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231005-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231004-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231003-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231002-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20231001-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20230930-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20230929-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20230928-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20230927-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20230926-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20230925-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20230924-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20230923-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20230922-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.14.0.dev20230921-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.2.dev20230920-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.2.dev20230919-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.2.dev20230918-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.2.dev20230917-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.2.dev20230916-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.2.dev20230915-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.2.dev20230914-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230913-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230912-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230911-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Collecting pyyaml<5.4.0,>=5.1 (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting tf-models-nightly (from tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230910-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230909-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230908-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230907-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230906-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230905-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230904-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230903-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230902-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230901-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230831-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230830-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230829-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230828-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230827-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230826-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230825-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230824-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230823-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230822-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230821-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230820-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230819-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230818-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230817-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230816-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230815-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230814-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230813-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230812-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230811-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.13.1.dev20230810-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
  Using cached tf_models_nightly-2.12.0.dev20230601-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Collecting pyyaml<6.0,>=5.1 (from tf-models-nightly->tflite-model-maker)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [54 lines of output]
  running egg_info
  writing lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\AI\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "D:\AI\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "D:\AI\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 321, in run
      self.find_sources()
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 329, in find_sources
      mm.run()
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 551, in run
      self.add_defaults()
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 589, in add_defaults
      sdist.add_defaults(self)
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 112, in add_defaults
      super().add_defaults()
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
      self._add_defaults_ext()
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
      self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
    File "C:\Users\user.sample\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-6tk7ndfw\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
      raise AttributeError(attr)
  AttributeError: cython_sources
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76710304/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+cython_sources