# install ansible docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, pip, ansible

I have ansible playbook task

```
- name: isntall ansible docker-compose
  ansible.builtin.pip:
    name: docker-compose
```

to install the ansible docker-compose module with the usage of ansible built-in pip, and getting an error that I can't understand

```
TASK [setup : isntall ansible docker-compose] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/bin/python", "-m", "pip.__main__", "install", "docker-compose"], "msg": "stdout: Collecting docker-compose\n  Using cached docker_compose-1.29.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114 kB)\nCollecting PyYAML<6,>=3.10 (from docker-compose)\n  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)\n  Installing build dependencies: started\n  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: started\n  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'\n\n:stderr:   error: subprocess-exited-with-error\n  \n  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.\n  │ exit code: 1\n  ╰─> [54 lines of output]\n      running egg_info\n      writing lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/PKG-INFO\n      writing dependency_links to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/dependency_links.txt\n      writing top-level names to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/top_level.txt\n      Traceback (most recent call last):\n        File \"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py\", line 353, in <module>\n          main()\n        File \"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py\", line 335, in main\n          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])\n                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n        File \"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py\", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel\n          return hook(config_settings)\n                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py\", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel\n          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])\n                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py\", line 295, in _get_build_requires\n          self.run_setup()\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py\", line 311, in run_setup\n          exec(code, locals())\n        File \"<string>\", line 271, in <module>\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py\", line 103, in setup\n          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)\n                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py\", line 185, in setup\n          return run_commands(dist)\n                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py\", line 201, in run_commands\n          dist.run_commands()\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py\", line 969, in run_commands\n          self.run_command(cmd)\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py\", line 963, in run_command\n          super().run_command(command)\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py\", line 988, in run_command\n          cmd_obj.run()\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py\", line 321, in run\n          self.find_sources()\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py\", line 329, in find_sources\n          mm.run()\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py\", line 551, in run\n          self.add_defaults()\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py\", line 589, in add_defaults\n          sdist.add_defaults(self)\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py\", line 112, in add_defaults\n          super().add_defaults()\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py\", line 251, in add_defaults\n          self._add_defaults_ext()\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py\", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext\n          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())\n                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n        File \"<string>\", line 201, in get_source_files\n        File \"/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-8zup8ye_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py\", line 107, in __getattr__\n          raise AttributeError(attr)\n      AttributeError: cython_sources\n      [end of output]\n  \n  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.\nerror: subprocess-exited-with-error\n\n× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.\n│ exit code: 1\n╰─> See above for output.\n\nnote: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.\n"}
```

To make this error a bit prettier I ran ansible pipe myself from terminal `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/bin/python -m pip install docker-compose` and the output is:

```
Collecting docker-compose
  Using cached docker_compose-1.29.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114 kB)
Collecting PyYAML<6,>=3.10 (from docker-compose)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [54 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      writing lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to lib3/PyYAML.egg-info/top_level.txt
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 963, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 321, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 329, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 551, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 589, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 112, in add_defaults
          super().add_defaults()
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
        File "/private/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/pip-build-env-aktl31m3/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.
```

Any idea how to fix that issue, and what is wrong??
I need to run tasks like this:

```
- name: stop existing common abbooom docker containers
  docker_compose:
    project_src: ../
    state: absent
```

and to do so I need to have docker-compose module installed

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unable to load docker-compose. Try `pip install docker-compose`. Error: Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/folders/jv/whrfm1y145gfkndt6clmn4pr0000gp/T/ansible_docker_compose_payload_w6qn8ckh/ansible_docker_compose_payload.zip/ansible_collections/community/docker/plugins/modules/docker_compose.py\", line 522, in <module>\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'compose'\n"}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76710304/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+cython_sources The bottom line is: `docker-compose` has a buggy dependency `PyYAML<6`; it must be upgraded. See also https://github.com/docker/compose/issues?q=is%3Aissue+cython_sources

Comment: oh my god, thanks, Ideally I'm planned to add different tasks for different OSes, but now I'm not sure it make much sense