# Can someone fix this? pip install intents

Tags: python

I'm not sure why this is failing but I need help to fix it please I've been trying to fix it for about 2 hours now and can't figure it out. I have tried to restart my computer, look it up on google etc. but nothing is helping at all. am I missing something or is this a internal problem. If you find the problem, can you show me how you found it too? I'm trying to learn.

```
         Collecting intents
      Using cached intents-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
    Collecting dacite<2.0.0,>=1.6.0 (from intents)
      Using cached dacite-1.8.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (15 kB)
    Collecting google-cloud-dialogflow<3.0.0,>=2.0.0 (from intents)
      Using cached google_cloud_dialogflow-2.27.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
    Collecting pyyaml<6.0.0,>=5.4.1 (from intents)
      Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
      Installing build dependencies ... done
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
      × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
      │ exit code: 1
      ╰─> [54 lines of output]
          running egg_info
          writing lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
          writing dependency_links to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
          writing top-level names to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
          Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
              main()
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
              json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
              return hook(config_settings)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
              return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
              self.run_setup()
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
              exec(code, locals())
            File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
              return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
              return run_commands(dist)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
              dist.run_commands()
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
              self.run_command(cmd)
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 963, in run_command
              super().run_command(command)
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
              cmd_obj.run()
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 321, in run
              self.find_sources()
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 329, in find_sources
              mm.run()
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 551, in run
              self.add_defaults()
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 589, in add_defaults
              sdist.add_defaults(self)
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 112, in add_defaults
              super().add_defaults()
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 251, in add_defaults
              self._add_defaults_ext()
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 336, in _add_defaults_ext
              self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
            File "C:\Users\hicks\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5y4riome\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
              raise AttributeError(attr)
          AttributeError: cython_sources
          [end of output]
    
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> See above for output.
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: which python you are using

Comment: Latest, 3.12.1 currently

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue importing PyYAML, cltk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76707475/issue-importing-pyyaml-cltk)

Comment: it continues to download on PyYAML 5.4.1 how do i change it

Answer (score 0):

below method you can do to workaround

1. clone repo and then in `pyproject.toml` file change the `pyyaml` dependency version to latest, and then do `python3 -m pip install .` in the cloned repo
2. install without dependency and then add dependency of `pyyaml` in the project dependency. so to do so  run `python3 -m pip install intents --no-deps` and `python3 -m pip install pyyaml`

Comment: hey, im trying to run python3 -m pip install in the cloned repo but cant, do u have discord?

Comment: After update pyproject.toml do run `pip install  .`