How do I install Yotta through pip
I am unable to install Yotta on my Windows 11 system. I have installed the dependencies but when I execute the following on python 3.12, pip version 24.0, it fails.
pip install -U yotta

The error message I recieve seems to be related to the python PyYAML module, but I am not sure how. Here is the message:
Collecting pyyaml<6.0,>=5.1 (from valinor<2.0,>=1.1.4->yotta)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [54 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      writing lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to lib3\PyYAML.egg-info\top_level.txt
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 271, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 184, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 200, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 968, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 321, in run
          self.find_sources()
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 329, in find_sources
          mm.run()
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 550, in run
          self.add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\egg_info.py", line 588, in add_defaults
          sdist.add_defaults(self)
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\sdist.py", line 102, in add_defaults
          super().add_defaults()
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 250, in add_defaults
          self._add_defaults_ext()
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\sdist.py", line 335, in _add_defaults_ext
          self.filelist.extend(build_ext.get_source_files())
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "<string>", line 201, in get_source_files
        File "C:\Users\dobbob11\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-brjy816p\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]


https://stackoverflow.com/a/76769988/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bpyyaml%5D+AttributeError%3A+cython_sources

Also yotta: https://pypi.org/project/yotta/ The last release was in 2020. https://github.com/ARMmbed/yotta Git repository is archived (closed). Are you sure you need this outdated abd abandoned project?

I am trying to develop software in C/C++ targeting the BBC micro:bit, this is how they recommend to do it

PyYAML 5.4.1 is broken. Install yotta this way: pip install yotta PyYAML==5.3.1

PyYAML 5.4.1 is broken. Install PyYAML 5.3.1 then install Yotta. Or you can install them together:
pip install PyYAML==5.3.1 yotta


this gives the same error as my comment in the above answer

@BobsonTobson It's a completely different error and should be discussed in a separate question. Accept one of the answers and ask a different question with more details about your error.

but it is an error with the answer you provided, as it did not solve my problem, nor did the above answer, so I will not be accepting them.

@BobsonTobson The error "could not build wheel for cryptography" is a completely different error, not related to PyYAML's "AttributeError: cython_sources".

The issue seems to be related to the PyYAML dependency while installing yotta. Read the entire answer first. Then try the following.
First, try installing PyYAML separately to ensure it installs correctly:
pip install pyyaml==5.4.1

After successfully installing PyYAML, try installing yotta again.
pip install -U yotta

If it doesn't work for you, then create a virtual environment and activate it:
python -m venv yotta-env
yotta-env\Scripts\activate

Upgrade pip and setuptools:
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools

Install yotta:
pip install -U yotta

Ensure you have all the necessary build tools for Python. On Windows, this usually means having Visual Studio Build Tools installed.
You can install them using:
pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel

However, if there are still issues, try specifying the exact versions for dependencies as shown in the error message.
Good luck!

I tried to install PyYAML seperately as you said, and it failed in the same way, so I created a virtual environment and updated setuptools and wheel, but it still failed. This time it said it could not build wheel for cryptography, and it is required for pyproject.toml based projects

I've installed yotta on macOS as below.
$ python3 -m venv ~/venv/yotta

$ . ~/venv/yotta/bin/activate

(yotta) $ cat constraints.txt
cmsis-pack-manager==0.2.10  # 2020-03-31
pyocd==0.25.0   # 2020-03-11
pyyaml==5.3.1   # 2020-03-19
yotta==0.20.5   # 2020-03-06

(yotta) $ pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
:

(yotta) $ pip install -c constraints.txt yotta
:

[UPDATE]
Unfortunately, I need to downgrade to the following versions to complete yotta build for my project

python: 3.6
arm-none-eabi-gcc: 10.3


Another solution is to use a docker image built with yotta.
[UPDATE]
Here is an example of docker image consists of yotta and arm-none-eabi-gcc.

https://github.com/carlosperate/docker-microbit-toolchain

The image intends to build yotta modules for micro:bit but I suppose you can use it for any target using arm-none-eabi-gcc.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
