Error installing Fooocus using pip (AttributeError: cython_sources)
I'm having troubles during the installation of Fooocus using pip, while processing the requirements_versions.txt
I'm on Windows 10, Python 3.12
I got the error both in standard cmd and windows power shell, run as administrator.
Command:
pip install -r requirements_versions.txt
  File "<string>", line 204, in get_source_files
        File "C:\Users\Samuel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8secg_pn\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 107, in __getattr__
          raise AttributeError(attr)
      AttributeError: cython_sources
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

This is the content in requirements_versions.txt
torchsde==0.2.5
einops==0.4.1
transformers==4.30.2
safetensors==0.3.1
accelerate==0.21.0
pyyaml==6.0
Pillow==9.2.0
scipy==1.9.3
tqdm==4.64.1
psutil==5.9.5
pytorch_lightning==1.9.4
omegaconf==2.2.3
gradio==3.41.2
pygit2==1.12.2
opencv-contrib-python==4.8.0.74
httpx==0.24.1
onnxruntime==1.16.3
timm==0.9.2


https://stackoverflow.com/a/76710304/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/76874192/7976758 . Use pyyaml 5.3.1 or 6.0.1. Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+cython_sources
